# Django objects being "non subscriptable" leads me to write redundant code

Tags: python, django, object, models

Django objects aren't "subscriptable" meaning if you have `user.name` you can't define it with `user['name']` meaning you can't dynamically load up an object with info.

```
info = {'first_name': 'Artur', 'last_name': 'Sapek'}

me = User()
for i in info:
    me[i] = info[i]
```

brings up `TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable` and I find myself writing code like

```
info = {'first_name': 'Artur', 'last_name': 'Sapek'}

if 'first_name' in info: me.first_name = info['first_name']
if 'last_name' in info: me.first_name = info['last_name']
so on...
```

(It requires if-statements as well because there is more info and it is not always complete - this isn't my actual code)

Is there any better way to do this with Django objects, which don't have the flexibility to use bracket notation like you can with lists, dicts, and strings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) is what you're looking for.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
for attr, value in info.items():
    setattr(me, attr, value)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Remember to come back and hit the 'accept' button if your question was answered :)

Answer (score 9):

Why not do the following:

```
info = {'first_name': 'Artur', 'last_name': 'Sapek'}
user = User(**info)
```

Of course if you are using `contrib.auth`'s `User` model you'll need to provide the required fields.